# Getting rid of back navigation in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation, storyboard

I made a few controllers using Xcode as seen below:

[image]

As you can see, the first view controller is formatted the way I would like. There is no way to go back from it and the screen looks like a normal app screen. The next two view controllers look very different and have this built in back navigation when users swipe down. I would like to get rid of this navigation and have the view controllers only perform navigations when the specified segues are activated. It must be a simple fix but I have not been able to find anything on the internet that directs me to where I could go to change this.

[image]

I want this view controller to look like the first one in the sequence as it takes up the entire screen and does not allow the user to navigate back.

I have tried changing the segue type and nothing has worked to fix the issue.

Comment: [setNavigationBarHidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621885-setnavigationbarhidden)?

Comment: Or you can use different type of transition for the segue.

Answer (score 1):

Basically every present segue in iOS 13 is set to .pageSheet as default,
You should set UIModalPresentationStyle to .fullScreen to get the desired effect.

To do it in storyboard select all the destination ViewControllers and set presentation to fullScreen
[image]

Comment: I can't find the full screen option in the view controller settings. Where should I go to set it?

Comment: Check the updated answer, added an image to help you find it, select those viewcontrollers and you'd find it in the picture.